# Need To Add Text To Each End Of A Path

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am drawing a diagram of a switch network in WPF.  I can add the switches and the connections between them to the diagram. the connections are drawn as Path with LineGeometry as the Data:

```
Shapes.Path path1;
path1 = new Shapes.Path();
path1.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
path1.StrokeThickness = 1;

LineGeometry line1 = new LineGeometry();
path1.Data = line1;
```

I add  the line to the thumb that I am using to represent the switch:

```
SwitchAsThumb thumb1 = new SwitchAsThumb;
thumb1.StartLines.Add(line1);
```

Where SwitchAsThumb is defined as:

```
public class SwitchAsThumb : Thumb
{
    public List<LineGeometry> EndLines { get; private set; }
    public List<LineGeometry> StartLines { get; private set; }

}
```

and this method in my window xaml.cs file to update the end point position of the path:

```
public void UpdateSwitchConnections(SwitchAsThumb thumb)
{
    double left = Canvas.GetLeft(thumb);
    double top = Canvas.GetTop(thumb);

    for (int i = 0; i < thumb.StartLines.Count; i++)
        thumb.StartLines[i].StartPoint = new Point(left + thumb.ActualWidth / 2, top + thumb.ActualHeight / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < thumb.EndLines.Count; i++)
        thumb.EndLines[i].EndPoint = new Point(left + thumb.ActualWidth / 2, top + thumb.ActualHeight / 2);
}
```

I was thinking I could place labels or similar at the same points on the canvas  when the lines are updated, but I'm not sure the labels would move when the user drags the switches around to re-arrange the diagram.  The method I've implemented to re-draw the thumbs when the user drags them around could probably be updated to move the labels but I'm hoping there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: You could try creating a new `ControlTemplate` to the thumb and add the label there, I think that could work for you. If you don't want to recreate the template, you could wrap the `Thumb` in another object and add a template to it.

Comment: I thought about that.  I already have a ControlTemplate on the thumb that contains a textblock.  I could add another textblock but  I wasn't sure if when I position the new one the thumb doesn't move. The textblock that labels the end of the path needs to be part of the Thumb, but positioned at the end of the path.  I will try that and see what happens.